# Running php mysql from jquery UI dialogue box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface

I cant figure out how I can run a php mysql query when a jquery ui dialogue box opens.

I'm trying to make a dialogue box say 'do you really want to delete database?' and if the user clicks yes, then the php will run, how can I do this?

Please answer in an easy to understand way, cos I'm kind of new to coding. thanks!

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: When posting an answer, please provide as much detail as possible.  If there is an article you were unsure of how to implement a particular task, provide the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code wouldn't run *in the dialog*, but the HTML in the dialog can invoke a request to the server where the PHP code runs.  Since this is a jQuery UI dialog box, then presumably it can contain any HTML you specify?  In that case, it might contain a simple form:

```
<form method="POST" action="somePage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="database" value="someValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
</form>
```

With this simple form, when a user clicks "Yes" the page will navigate to `somePage.php` as a POST request, sending the `someValue` value for the `database` key.  Which can then be accessed on `somePage.php`:

```
$database = $_POST['database'];
```

The idea here is that the form would include some value to identify the "database" being "deleted" by the user.  Then `somePage.php` would know what the user is trying to do and do it (after validating that the user is *allowed* to do that, however you perform your validation logic).  Whatever the PHP code is which does that is up to you.

Ultimately, you just need to POST to a page which runs the server-side code.  And that POST needs to include any values that server-side code will need to do what it has to do.

Comment: thanks but sadly I dont think it can actually contain html, however for future reference, what I did in the end was make the 'delete' button on the dialogue box redirect to another page, which ran the delete query, which then redirected back to the original page

Comment: @binyamin: You must be using some other tool, because a jQuery UI Dialog most certainly *can* contain HTML.  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/